# implementing click event on a dropdown menu at angular

Tags: html, angular

I want to implement a dropdown menu that when you click on a button a menu is opened up.
and in each of the labels that displayed on the menu are buttons,
I succeeded, the problem was that I could not implement succesfully the "on click event"
for each of those buttons.

this is the html code:

```
   <sol-button
      [variant]="(t.menuOpen) ? 'primary' : 'basic'"
      [matMenuTriggerFor]="x.menu"
      [iconPositionedFront]="AIIcon"
      [size]="'large'"
      id="menu-button"
      #t="matMenuTrigger"
    >
    </sol-button>

    <sol-floating-menu
      #x="floatingMenu"
      [menuItems]="menuItems"
      [variant]="'variant'"
    >
    <button *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" (click)="menuItem.action()">
      {{ menuItem.label }}
    </button>
  </sol-floating-menu>
```

and this is the typescript code:

```
menuItems : any = [
 {
  label: "Expand",
  action: () => {
    console.log('Clicked on Expand');
    // Add your logic for Expand here
   }
  },
 {
   "label": "Simplify",
    ction: () => {
    console.log('Clicked on Simplify');
 // Add your logic for Expand here
  },
  {
   "label": "Translate ",
    action: () => {
     console.log('Clicked on Translate');
     // Add your logic for Expand here
   }
  },
  {
   "label": "Change tone",
    action: () => {
    console.log('Clicked on Change tone');
    // Add your logic for Expand here
   }
  }
];
```

Comment: I think you don't have `<ng-content>` anywhere in your `<sol-floating-menu>` component

Comment: so what should I do/

Comment: put `<ng-content>` in place where  you want your buttons from parrent component be rendered in the child component

Comment: i tried to place it but it does not compile,
where would you put it?
          <sol-floating-menu
          #x="floatingMenu"
          [menuItems]="menuItems"
          [variant]="'variant'"
        >
        <button *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" (click)="handleClick(menuItem)">
          {{ menuItem.label }}
          </button>
      </sol-floating-menu>

Comment: inside of your sol-floating-menu template put `<ng-content></ng-content>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems there might be a typo in your TypeScript code. In the `menuItems` array, the second object has a typo (`ction` instead of `action`).

Let's correct that:

```
menuItems: any = [
  {
   label: "Expand",
   action: () => {
   console.log('Clicked on Expand');
   // Add your logic for Expand here
  }
},
{
 label: "Simplify",
 action: () => {
  console.log('Clicked on Simplify');
  // Add your logic for Simplify here
  }
},
{
 label: "Translate",
 action: () => {
  console.log('Clicked on Translate');
  // Add your logic for Translate here
 }
},
 {
  label: "Change tone",
  action: () => {
  console.log('Clicked on Change tone');
  // Add your logic for Change tone here
 }
}
];
```

define the handleClick() function:

```
    handleClick(menuItem: any) {
      menuItem.action();
    }
```

Now, each object in the `menuItems` array has a `label` and an `action` function, which should be correctly triggered when the corresponding button is clicked in the dropdown menu

```
<sol-floating-menu #x="floatingMenu" [menuItems]="menuItems" [variant]="'variant'">
<button *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" (click)="handleClick(menuItem)">
{{ menuItem.label }}
</button>
```

This setup should allow the `action()` associated with each menu item to be triggered correctly when its corresponding button is clicked within the dropdown menu.

Comment: thanks but IT still does not work,:
and that code:
" <sol-floating-menu #x="floatingMenu" [menuItems]="menuItems" [variant]="'variant'">
<button *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" (click)="menuItem.action()">
 {{ menuItem.label }}
</button>

that code is similar to my code..

Comment: plz check it now

Comment: I tried but it still does not fire the event when I click on a button on the dropdown menu